# Drilldown functionality with AngularJS using ng-repeat property and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to do the exact same thing as this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3ntcnxxb/) (***The example is mine***) but using angular. In the normal HTML I have a parent **tr** with its own child **tr** so when I run the example I can see 
that the child records that are related to its parent **tr**

Then I start doing this in Angular but now Im confused because I'm using ng-repeat and a JSON structure to populate the data so now I only have this piece of code, I put this as the parent but I don't know how to deal with the "child":

```
       <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="d in category" class="parent">
              <td class="expand"></td>
              <td ng-bind="d.cat"></td>
              <td ng-bind="d.LW$"></td>
              <td ng-bind="d.LW"></td>
              <td ng-bind="d.L4W"></td>
              <td ng-bind="d.L13W"></td>
              <td ng-bind="d.L52W"></td>
          </tr>
       </tbody>
```

Here is my code with the angular version: https://jsfiddle.net/228wkfej/

Comment: looking now, but one quick thing, you dont need the ng-bind there, you can just put the d.cat for example in the html like so {{d.cat}}

Comment: Thanks for your time.

So when is a good case to use ng-bind and when not?

Comment: I think the best way to go about this is to create a different data structure than you have right now, if its properly nested the exact way your table is (with arrays for each drill down) then you can ng-repeat multiple times which I think is the best way to approach this problem: here is an different example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6aqtj/1/

Comment: hope that makes sense and gets you on track, post here if its not!

Comment: Actually what I'm going to use at the end are Web services, the response is comming in JSON, for the child level Im going to use a different WS thats why I try to sinulate this with a differente name in the $scope variable in my example "$scope.categories, $scope.subcat"

Comment: thats gonna be a pain, can you manipulate the data? like I said, just put one in the other. and then you ng-repeat though categories, and then ng-repeat through subcat... all under one scope object